# Facebook Login URL BLOCKED with correct OAuth Redirect URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth, devise, facebook-oauth

I get this error everytime I try to loggin with my account from my website, there comes an alert from facebook saying that the URL has been blocked because it hasnt been whitelisted in the app Client oAuth-Settings.
However, here are my client oAuth Settings

[image]

This is exactly the url that the link has that redirects to the facebook login.

```
<%= link_to user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path, class:"btn btn-primary login-with-btn d-flex justify-content-start" do %>
  <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/145/145802.svg" alt="facebook icon" style="width: 25px; margin: 0 20px 0 5px">
  <h5>Login with Facebook <span class="badge bg-primary text-light">NEW</span></h5>
<% end %>
```

Why is this the case?

I am handling the facebook login with devise and omniauth, its working perfectly fine with google signup.
Do I have to have my website be reviewed for verification?

Thank you so much for your help!
Vincent

Comment: `http://darkerr.co/users/auth/facebook` maybe be the URL on your end, from where you trigger the auth flow - but if you look closely, the `redirect_uri` parameter passed in the actual FB login dialog URL, is `http://darkerr.co/users/auth/facebook/callback`. So that is the URL that needs to be put into your app settings.

Comment: omg it worked! Thank you so much! How did you know that?

Comment: Went to the site shown in your screenshot & tested it :-)